# Do I have a memory leak using UIReferenceLibraryViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, instruments

I'm building a language learning app that makes use of `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` which I manually present from my view controller as follows:

```
let referenceLibraryVC = UIReferenceLibraryViewController(term: term)
presentViewController(referenceLibraryVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

`UIReferenceLibraryViewController` has no delegate property and is responsible for dismissing itself.

Profiling my app for allocations using `Instruments` I see that each time I present a UIReferenceLibraryViewController, the `#Persistent` count increments but does not decrement when the UIReferenceLibraryViewController is dismissed.

Is this a memory leak or is instruments just not detecting UIReferenceLibraryViewController's deallocation.  If this is a leak is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Have you figure a way to workaround that leak? Seems the leak is still appear on iOS 12.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question with you. 
Firstly I think it is because of the new language, so I used Objective C to demo it. The result was the same!
Further more, if you call its class method`class func dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm(term: String) -> Bool` can also result in memory leaks.
Using Profile to analyze the memory, I was told the source of leaks is `CFString`.
Awkward!!!